# Area between great circle and circle of latitude

Tags: area, spherical-geometry

#### Question

> $B$ and $B'$ lie on a circle of latitude (black arc) of a unit sphere. The great arc between $B$ and $B'$ is also shown (the orange arc). Given:
>
> - the azimuthal difference $\alpha$ between $B$ and $B'$,
> - the zenith angle for the circle $\theta$ of latitude,
>
> what is the area on the unit sphere between the two arcs between $B$ and $B'$?

I tried to approach the problem by first parametrizing the great circle and then integrating the length of the longitudinal arcs between $B$ and $B'$, but I don't know how to express the angle between the great circle and the $xOy$ plane.

I'm only aware of two special cases:

- when $\alpha=\pi$, the area is half of a spherical cap
  $$
    \displaystyle\int_0^{\theta}\pi\sin\theta\ \mathrm d\theta = \pi (1-\cos\theta),$$
- when $\theta=\pi/2$, the area is $0$ because the two arcs overlap.

#### Answers that would help my understanding of the question could

- express the angle between the great circle and $xOy$ plane and then look for the area, or
- use other methods that are perhaps more suitable or elegant.

[image: Illustration of the region whose area I am looking for]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Geodesic
>
> $$\cot \theta=a \cos(\phi-\beta)$$

Let the end points be $(\theta_{0},0)$ and $(\theta_{0},\phi_{0})$, then

$$\cot \theta_{0}=a \cos \beta=a \cos (\phi_{0}-\beta)$$

Now,

\begin{align*}
  \beta &= \frac{\phi_{0}}{2} \\
  a &= \frac{\cot \theta_{0}}{\cos \frac{\phi_{0}}{2}} \\
  dA &= \sin \theta \, d\theta \, d\phi \\
   A &= 2\int_{0}^{\beta} (\cos \theta_{0}-\cos \theta) \, d\phi \\
  &= 2\int_{0}^{\beta}
     \left(
       \cos \theta_{0}-
       \frac{\cot \theta}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2 \theta}}
     \right) d\phi \\
  &= 2\int_{0}^{\beta}
     \left[
       \cos \theta_{0}-
       \frac{a\cos (\phi-\beta)}{\sqrt{1+a^2 \cos^2 (\phi-\beta)}}
     \right] d\phi \\
  &= 2\int_{0}^{\beta}
     \left(
       \cos \theta_{0}-
       \frac{a\cos \phi}{\sqrt{1+a^2 \cos^2 \phi}}
     \right) d\phi \\
  &= 2\left[
        \beta \cos \theta_{0}-
        \tan^{-1} \left(
                    \frac{a\sin \beta}{\sqrt{1+a^2\cos^2 \beta}}
                  \right)
      \right] \\
  &= \phi_{0} \cos \theta_{0}-
     2\tan^{-1} \left(
                  \cos \theta_{0} \tan \frac{\phi_{0}}{2}
                \right)
\end{align*}

**Alternative Method**

Considering a spherical triangle with $a=b=\theta_{0}$ and $C=\phi_{0}$.

Now

\begin{align*}
  \tan \frac{A+B}{2} &=
  \frac{\cos \frac{a-b}{2}}{\cos \frac{a+b}{2}} \cot \frac{C}{2} \\[3pt]
  &= \frac{\cot \frac{\phi_{0}}{2}}{\cos \theta_{0}} \\[5pt]
  \Delta &= A+B+C-\pi \\[3pt]
  &= 2\tan^{-1} \frac{\cot \frac{\phi_{0}}{2}}{\cos \theta_{0}}+
     \phi_{0}-\pi \\[3pt]
  &= \phi_{0}-2\tan^{-1}
     \left( \cos \theta_{0} \tan \frac{\phi_{0}}{2} \right) \\[3pt]
  \text{the required area}
  &= \Delta-\int_{0}^{\theta_{0}} \int_{0}^{\phi_{0}}
      \sin \theta \, d\theta \, d\phi \\[3pt]
  &= \Delta-(1-\cos \theta_{0}) \phi_{0} \\[3pt]
  &=\phi_{0} \cos \theta_{0}-
     2\tan^{-1} \left(
                  \cos \theta_{0} \tan \frac{\phi_{0}}{2}
                \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm new to spherical trigonometry, so I would like to ask why is $\cot\theta=a\cos(\phi-\beta)$? Furthermore, what do $a$ and $\beta$ represent?

Comment: They are integration constants for geodesic equations.

Comment: Have you learnt calculus of variation?  May refer to [this](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/reh10/lectures/nst-mmii-handout2.pdf)

Comment: Answer updated with corrections.

Comment: Actually, an absolute value would take care of the sign. Thank you very much for showing these _two_ different approaches.